# Post JSON to PHP in AJAX for MongoDB Querying

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, mongodb

I am constructing a Javascript object. I am using the id of user who is logged in (from a session variable) and storing it as an attribute with AJAX.

I wanted to post the resulting object as JSON via AJAX to a PHP file which then inserts the document into a MongoDB database:

```
    var numpages=$('.page').length;

    var book=new Object();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'json',
        url: '../scripts/getUser.php',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            var user=JSON.parse(data);
            book.user=data.username;
        }
    });

        book.title=title;
        book.pages=new Array();

        var page;
        var link;

    for (var i=0;i<numpages;i++){
        var numlinks=$('#p'+i+' .link').length;
        page=new Object();
            page.text=$('#p'+i+' .textarea').text();
            page.links=new Array();

        for (var j=0;j<numlinks;j++){
            link=new Object();
            link.text=$('#p'+i+'l'+j+' .linktext').text();
            link.locale=$('#p'+i+'l'+j+' .locale').text();

            page.links.push(link);
        }
        book.pages.push(page);
    }

    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(book),
        url: '../scripts/addstory.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(msg) {
        //var story=JSON.parse(msg);
        console.log(msg);
            //alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'story';

$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://$dbhost");
$db = $m->$dbname;

$collection = $db->stories;

$story=$_POST['json'];

if (isset($story)){
$collection->save($story);
}
?>
```

The document is being inserted into the database but I get this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problem, first being that ajax is async unless you specify the async flag to false which you probably don't want to do so:

```
book.owner=data.username;
```

Is likely to actually be empty when you come to JSON encode in the second ajax call.

To solve this you can use JQuery promises like so:

```
$.get().done(function(data){
    /// extra processing
}).then(function(){ $.get() // etc });
```

This will ensure that one Ajax calls runs after the other.

As for the missing index you don't actually need to stringify your data at all instead you can just do:

```
$.get('some_url', {book: book})
```

And JQuery will actually serialize it for you ready for PHP.

Comment: Could you please explain the above code a bit more, please? How do I use this?

Comment: @user3066347 So the first `get` would be your first Ajax call. The stuff that goes in `done()` would be your after processing for that call, basically what you'd put in `success` normally. It uses a `then()` function to say that after all that run the next ajax call

Comment: @user3066347 it is good to note that there is a $.get and a $.post depending on what type of Ajax type you are calling

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work exclusively with JSON, you should set your content-type header to `application/json` and then read that content from PHP raw input:

The javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(book),
    url: '../scripts/addstory.php',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

The PHP:

```
$story = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

So really you just need to add one line of code and change another.

The reason `$_POST['json']` was not being populated is that nowhere did you define a query string (or let jQuery define for you) that has a key `json`.

You could have, for example done something like this:

```
data: {'json': JSON.stringify(book)}
```

And that would have populated `$POST['json']`, but again if all you are looking to do is pass around a JSON string and directly insert it into Mongo, there is no reason to use form-encoding for this at all, just work with raw POST data.

Note also the problem mentioned by @Sammaye about needing to properly work with event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
JSON.stringify(book),
```

creates an object something like:

```
{"title":"East of Eden","author":"John Steinbeck"}
```

better completely remove the JSON.stringify() bit and just pass the book variable

And it in the ajax call it should be type: "POST", not method: "POST"

So in your php script you can do

```
$_POST['title'];
$_POST['author'];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: No that will create a string which then PHP would need to decode

Comment: Yeps sorry, forgt to mention: remove the JSON.stringify completely